# Как экспортировать const из функции в React

Tags: react-native

Помогите не могу сообразить ток начинаю работать, есть два файла js
Первый файл:

```
function Raschet ({ navigation, style}) {
  const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState('3000');
  const [vozrast, setVozrast] = React.useState("");

return (
      <><SafeAreaView style={{display: (test1)}}> 
<View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Ошибка!</Text>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Расчет производится только для лиц достигших возраста 18 лет.</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModal(!modal)}>
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Хорошо</Text>
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{number}</Text> //Тут отображается переменная number
            </Pressable>
          </View>
</SafeAreaView>
  );

  }

 export { Raschet }
```

второй файл

```
function Raschet2 ({ navigation, style, number}) {

return (
      <><SafeAreaView style={{display: (test1)}}> 
<View style={styles.modalView}>
  <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{number}</Text> //Тут должна быть значение number из первого файла
            </Pressable>
          </View>
</SafeAreaView>
  );

  }

 export { Raschet }
```

Comment: Напрямую, экспортировать значения из фукнции-react нельзя. Как эти 2 компонента связаны между собой? Может у них есть общий родитель?

Comment: Не как не связаны

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать через `useContext` передать значение из одного элемента в другой. Точнее в первом сохранять значение в контекст, а во втором отображать.